# Different rows in separate columns SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

I am working on a SQL statement which gets different lines from a database into different columns.

db1:

```
id  | name
1   | Shoe
2   | Jacket
```

db2:

```
id |  type  | image
1  |  0     | image_1_1.jpg
1  |  1     | image_1_2.jpg
1  |  2     | image_1_3.jpg
2  |  0     | image_2_1.jpg
```

output should be

```
id  | name   | image0        |  image1         | image2
1   | Shoe   | image_1_1.jpg |  image_1_2.jpg  | image_1_3.jpg
2   | Jacket | image_2_1.jpg |                 |
```

image0 is where type = 0
image1 is where type = 1 etc

I've tried it on several ways, but I can't get it right.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: What you are trying to do is called pivoting the table. Some RDBMSs have built-in support for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of data transformation is known as a *pivot*.  Some databases have a pivot function that can convert the rows into columns.

If you do not have a pivot function then you can also use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to get the result:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.name,
  max(case when t2.`type` = 0 then t2.image else '' end) Image0,
  max(case when t2.`type` = 1 then t2.image else '' end) Image1,
  max(case when t2.`type` = 2 then t2.image else '' end) Image2
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id,  t1.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/911e5/5)